# protobuf-net List<> inheritance deserialization

Tags: c#, list, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have problem with deserialization using protobuf-net.

I have the following class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class CrazyList : List<string>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly string _foo;

    public CrazyList(string foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public CrazyList(){}

    public new void Add(string item)
    {
        Console.Write(item + foo); // Problem is here!

        base.Add(item);
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
var list = new CrazyList("world!");
list.Add("Hello ");

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, list);

    ms.Position = 0;

    var listDS = Serializer.Deserialize<CrazyList>(ms);
    listDS.Add("Goodbye ");
}
```

The method `Add` is firing before the `_foo` field deserialization is completed.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use this for the CrazList attribut;

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling=true)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As with XmlSerializer, something either **is** a list, or **is** a leaf. There is no "both". At the moment, it will detect "list", and won't look for leaf-members. You can change it to be a leaf (see Fredou's answer) but then it won't serialize the items.

Because of how the wire specification (by google, not me), there **is no** representation of the list itself: a repeated sequence is just: "item, item, item, item". So if something is a list there is literally nowhere I can store data relating to the list itself.

Frankly, the simplest option is to refactor to encapsulate, for example (being minimal for brevity):

```
class SomeWrapper {
    string Foo ...
    List<string> Items ... 
}
```

You *can* also probably cheat if you need to, by using the approach Fredou shows, and adding:

```
[ProtoMember(2)]
private IList<string> Items { get { return this; } }
```

Which will make it *look* like the minimal example above, without actually changing the model in any significant way.

Incidentally: providing a custom Add for a `List<T>` subclass is not recommended, and you **should not** rely on order of deserialization.